# Программа снятия скриншота в виде сервиса

Tags: c++

Проблема в том что если приложение сервсис то скриншот - черный экран
скриншот делаю средствами GDI+

Comment: Потому что Ваш сервис не "интерактивный". А такие сервисы имеют "свой личный рабочий стол". Либо делайте интерактивный сервис, либо делайте программу-компаньон, которая будет запускаться в сессии пользователя и пересылать сервису скрины.

Comment: а как сделать сервис интерактивным?

Comment: Это можно сделать как [ручками](http://lostechies.com/keithdahlby/2011/08/13/allowing-a-windows-service-to-interact-with-desktop-without-localsystem/) в свойствах сервиса, так и попытаться сделать [программно](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: А зачем вам сервис для этой цели?

Comment: Не помогло что руками, что добавлением флага SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS

Comment: Это по заданию.....
сервер в виде службы, делает скрины и отсылает клиентам...